# Hair is not generated perpendicular to the face

Tags: particles, hair

I'm new to blender, and I was following a tutorial to make grass, the point is, I haven't been able to follow it well since in one step you have to generate hair particles and render them as objects, but my hair particles are not generated in perpendicular to the deformed faces of my subdivided plane (deformed trying to get an organic irregular terrain)

[image]

While in the tutorial, the objects (arrows) come out perpendicular to the faces

[image]

I thought it could be the Normal Map, but I have no problem with that since it is the same as the tutorial

[image]

Here below I leave the tutorial

[image]

I appreciate the time to read all this.
And sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

[image]Finish using "apply scale": Ctrl + A -> Scale in object mode.
Then I recreated the hair

this was important: [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)